# How to capture passed --conf parameter in called DAG in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I am trying to run a DAG from REST API and pass some parameters to it. The DAG should be able to catch the parameters and use it. The problem is I am able to trigger the DAG from REST API,but the DAG is not able to catch the parameters passed. Is there a way to achieve this?

I am triggering the DAG from REST API as below.It passes the parameters in --conf

```
http://abcairflow.com:8090/admin/rest_api/api?api=trigger_dag\&dag_id=trigger_test_dag\&conf=%7B%22key%22%3A%2
```

How to capture the values passed in conf value in the called DAG. As far as I know the conf should take the URL encoded JSON format data.

DAG code:`

```
def run_this_func(**kwargs):
print(kwargs)

run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_this',
    python_callable=run_this_func,
    dag=dag
)`
```

Answer (score 3):

The external parameters passed are part of the `dag_run` object. They can be accessed as follows:

> API Request

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{"conf":"{\\"Key1\\":\\"Value1\\"}"}'

response = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/<dag_id>/dag_runs', headers=headers, data=data)
```

> DAG

```
 def run_this_func(**context):
    print("Received {} for key=message".format(context["dag_run"].conf))


run_this = PythonOperator(task_id="run_this", python_callable=run_this_func, provide_context=True, dag=dag)
```

Comment: How to access context["dag_run"].conf in custom operator's execute method? @Sravan

Answer (score 2):

I did not know that you could trigger a DAG with HTTP GET, but I've successfully triggered with conf using POST and following the documentation https://airflow.apache.org/api.html

For example triggering the dag "trigger_test_dag":

```
curl -X POST --data '"conf":"{\"key\":\"value\"}"' \
"http://abcairflow.com:8090/api/experimental/dags/trigger_test_dag/dag_runs"
```

Pay attention to the escaping of apostrophes as conf needs to be a string. I guess you can do a base 64 encode, and then decode in the DAG, to the string if you prefer that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not a well-documented feature, but there are examples of a DAG triggering another DAG with the `conf` set and the target DAG using it. See [example_trigger_controller_dag](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_controller_dag.py) and [example_trigger_target_dag](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_target_dag.py). DAGs triggered by an operator, REST API, or CLI should all pass the `conf` parameter in the same way.

`conf` is accessible inside the context, so you'll need to make sure you pass `provide_context=True` when using a `PythonOperator`.

```
def run_this_func(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs['conf'])

run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_this',
    python_callable=run_this_func,
    dag=dag,
    provide_context=True,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This one took some digging as I wanted to use the conf to create a dynamic workflow, not just to be used in other operators. To use the conf parameters in the overall DAG:

```py
args = {"owner": "me", "depends_on_past": False}

with DAG(
         dag_id="my_dag",
         default_args=args
         schedule_interval="@daily",
         start_date=dats_ago(1)
        ) as dag

conf = dag.get_dagrun(execution_date=dag.get_latest_execution_date()).conf
```

So if the arguments you passed in the conf were

```py
{"table_names": ["table1", "table2", "table3"]}
```

You can access the table names list by doing

```py
table_names = conf["tables_names"]
```