# Why am I getting transient errors when trying to use DAG.get_dagrun() in Airflow/Google Composer?

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Been looking at ways to access the dag run config JSON and build my actual DAG and underlaying tasks dynamically depending on what's there.

As the Jinja templating is somewhat limited for my use I've opted to use 'vanilla' python, using functions to build out my tasks.

The backbone of all this is being able to access the config JSON which I found out how to in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68455786/5687904

However, as I am using Airflow 1.10.12 (Composer 1.13.3) I had to edit the above a bit with using older/deprecated attributes instead so what I got to is:

`conf = dag.get_dagrun(execution_date=dag.latest_execution_date).conf`

I got this to work in a new DAG for testing, here a minimum working example with any private data stripped:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
from airflow.models import Variable
from dependencies.airflow_utils import (
    DBT_IMAGE
)
from dependencies.kube_secrets import (
    GIT_DATA_TESTS_PRIVATE_KEY
)
# Default arguments for the DAG
default_args = {
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "owner": "airflow",
    "retries": 0,
    "start_date": datetime(2021, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0),
    'dataflow_default_options': {
        'project': 'my-gcp_project',
        'region': 'europe-west1'
        }
}

# Create the DAG
dag = DAG("test_conf_strings2", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None)
# DBT task creation function
conf = dag.get_dagrun(execution_date=dag.latest_execution_date).conf
def dynamic_full_refresh_strings(conf, arguments):  
    if conf.get("full-refresh") and 'dbt snapshot' in arguments:
        return ' --vars "full-refresh: true"'
    elif conf.get("full-refresh"):
        return conf.get("full-refresh")
    else:
        return ""

def task_dbt_run(conf, name, arguments, **kwargs):
    return KubernetesPodOperator(
    image=DBT_IMAGE,
    task_id="dbt_run_{}".format(name),
    name="dbt_run_{}".format(name),
    secrets=[
        GIT_DATA_TESTS_PRIVATE_KEY,
    ],
    startup_timeout_seconds=540,
    arguments=[arguments + dynamic_full_refresh_strings(conf, arguments)],
    dag=dag,
    get_logs=True,
    image_pull_policy="Always",
    resources={"request_memory": "512Mi", "request_cpu": "250m"},
    retries=3,
    namespace="default",
    cmds=["/bin/bash", "-c"]
)

# DBT commands
dbt_bqtoscore = f"""
    {clone_repo_simplified_cmd} &&
    cd bigqueryprocessing/data &&
    dbt run --profiles-dir .dbt --models execution_engine_filter"""

# Create all tasks for the dag
dbt_run_bqtoscore = task_dbt_run(conf, "bqtoscore", dbt_bqtoscore)

# Task dependencies setting
dbt_run_bqtoscore
```

However, when I tried adding this logic to my main DAG I started getting `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`.

After checking everything like a madman and doing a lot of diffchecker I confirmed there is no difference.

To ensure I am not going entirely crazy I even copied my working testing DAG and just changed the name to something else so it doesn't conflict with the original.
I got the error again, for essentially 1:1 copy of the dag!

So what's happening here judging by the error is that the same code for `conf = dag.get_dagrun(execution_date=dag.latest_execution_date).conf` produces different results in dags whose only difference is the dag name.
In my working tests I get the correct JSON I pass or simply {} if nothing is passed hence no error.
But in the erroring ones it is a None which causes the issue.

Does anybody have any ideas what might be happening here?
Or at least ideas of what tests/debugging I should do to dig deeper?

Answer (score 0):

Add a task PythonOperator prior to the main task; which basically calculates what `dynamic_full_refresh_strings` returns, and pass that info from first task to second (using x_com push/pull or setting in dag_run.conf or any other way)